# C memcpy behaviour with dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays, memcpy

Please look that after `memcpy`, I am changing the values in source matrix. They are automatically being replaced in destination. Further when I change destination array values they come to source array. Why is this happening?
Interestingly even after deleting the destination array by `free` command the values still remain the source. Please let me know this. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double *** double3d(long int dim1,long int dim2,long int dim3)
{
    long int i,j,k;
    double ***array;
    array=(double ***)malloc(dim1*sizeof(double **));
    for(i=0;i<dim1;i++)
    {
     array[i]=(double **)malloc(dim2*sizeof(double *));
     for(j=0;j<dim2;j++)
      array[i][j]=(double *)malloc(dim3*sizeof(double ));
    }
    return array;
}// end double3d

void summ(double ***A,double ***B, double ****C)
{
    int i ,j ,k;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            for(k=0;k<5;k++)
                (*C)[i][j][k] = A[i][j][k] + B[i][j][k];
}

void main()
{
    int i,j,k,nx,ny;
    double ***M1, ***M2, ***M3, ***M4,***M5,***M6;
    nx=5;ny=5;
    M1=double3d(10,nx,ny);
    M2=double3d(10,nx,ny);
    M3=double3d(10,nx,ny);
    M4=double3d(5,nx,ny);
    M5=double3d(5,nx,ny);
    M6=(double ***)malloc(10*sizeof(double **));

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
            for(k=0;k<ny;k++)
            {
                M1[i][j][k]=i;
                M2[i][j][k]=1;
            }
    }

    // Note random values are in M4 and M5 as they are not initalised
    memcpy(M6,     M4, 5 * sizeof(double **));
    memcpy(M6+5,   M5, 5 * sizeof(double **));

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
          for(k=0;k<ny;k++)
          {
               M4[i][j][k]=200;
               M5[i][j][k]=700;
          }
    }

    printf(" printing M6 Memcpy before addition\n");
    for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
    {
       for(k=0;k<ny;k++)
           printf("%f ",M6[4][j][k]);
       printf("\n");
       for(k=0;k<ny;k++)
           printf("%f ",M6[9][j][k]);
       printf("\n");
    }
    // calling for non memcpy array
    summ(M1,M2,&M3); printf(" Non memcpy output last value : %f \n",M3[9][nx-1][ny-1]);
    // calling for memcpy
    summ(M1,M2,&M6); printf(" memcpy output last value : %f \n",M6[9][nx-1][ny-1]);
    printf(" printing M6 Memcpy for two sets after addtion\n");
    for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
    {
       for(k=0;k<ny;k++)
           printf("%f ",M6[4][j][k]);
       printf("\n");
    }
    for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
    {
       for(k=0;k<ny;k++)
           printf("%f ",M6[9][j][k]);
       printf("\n");
    }

    free(M6);// cleared M6

    printf(" printing M4 Memcpy after deleting M6\n");
    for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
    {
       for(k=0;k<ny;k++)
           printf("%.1f ,%.1f ,%.1f ,%.1f ,%.1f ",M4[0][j][k],M4[1][j][k],M4[2][j][k],M4[3][j][k],M4[4][j][k]);
       printf("\n");
    }

    printf(" printing M5 Memcpy after deleting M6\n");
    for(j=0;j<nx;j++)
    {
       for(k=0;k<ny;k++)
           printf("%.1f ,%.1f ,%.1f ,%.1f ,%.1f ",M5[0][j][k],M5[1][j][k],M5[2][j][k],M5[3][j][k],M5[4][j][k]);
       printf("\n");
    }
 }
```

Comment: There's no dynamic array in your code!!

Comment: Please oh please don't become another [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). Being called that is *not* a compliment.

Comment: @SouravGhosh double3d creates a dynamic 3d array

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please don't take it otherwise. I am learner, I don't know why this is happening. pl run and tell why this is happening, by the way I have compiled it using gcc

Comment: Maybe `***` pointers are too much for learning.

Comment: Being a 3-star (`***`) C programmer is **not** a compliment!

Comment: Please read [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). It contains an example showing why multiple levels of indirection should be avoided.

Comment: @tilz0R wanted to work on 3d data time,latitude and longitude therefore ***

Comment: Wouldn't a *structure* with those data in separate member fields be a better alternative?

Comment: @ Lundin thanks man got another angle after reading your reply, very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" here is that you misunderstand (apparently) what `memcpy` does.

With

```
memcpy(M6,     M4, 5 * sizeof(double **));
```

what you are basically doing is

```
M6[0] = M4[0];
M6[1] = M4[1];
// etc...
```

I.e. you are copying the *pointers* and not what they point to.

When call `free(M6)` you only free the memory that `M6` is pointing to. But the data pointed to by e.g. `M6[0]` *and* `M4[0]` still exists, and is still pointed to by `M4[0]`.